# Проверка на отсутствие циклических ссылок при сборке из нескольких проектов

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Некоторые компоненты слабо связанного кода находятся в одной сборке. Хотелось бы контролировать отсутствие между ними циклических ссылок на этапе компиляции, не разбивая сборку. Наиболее логичным решением выглядит использование нескольких проектов сборок, которые потом компилируются в одну сборку. Циклические ссылки предотвращаются стандартным механизмом работы проектов, а сборка сливается.

Есть ли такая технология для Microsoft Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать компилировать не в целую сборку (.dll), а в объектный файл (.netmodule). Для этого нужно или строить при помощи msbuild, либо открыть файл проекта вручную, найти строку вида `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` и поменять её на `<OutputType>Module</OutputType>`. (Учтите, компиляция этого через Visual Studio считается неподдерживаемым сценарием. Но у меня работало.)

Затем, для компоновки модулей в assembly вам нужно вручную вызвать компоновщик. Например, в каком-либо post-build step'е:

```
call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
set M1=$(SolutionDir)Module\$(OutDir)Module.netmodule
set M1PDB=$(SolutionDir)Module\$(OutDir)Module.pdb
set M2=$(SolutionDir)Main\$(OutDir)Main.netmodule
set ENTRY=Main.Program.Main
link /ltcg /assemblymodule:"%M1%" "%M2%" /entry:%ENTRY% /subsystem:CONSOLE /out:"$(SolutionDir)Program.exe" /debug
copy /b %M1% "$(SolutionDir)"
copy /b %M1PDB% "$(SolutionDir)"
```

Разумеется, вам придётся подставить нужные пути вручную.

Вот [большое исследование по теме вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2609056/276994).

(Уверен, это всё можно автоматизировать при помощи msbuild, но я не знаю, как именно.)

Answer (score 2):

Несколько сборок можно склеить в одну уже после компиляции, используя утилиту [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx).

Она есть на [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge):

```
Install-Package ilmerge
```

Формат вызова:

```
ilmerge
  /lib:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"
  /lib:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"
  /targetplatform:v4
  /out:out.dll mydll1.dll mydll2.dll
```

пути стоит подправить на актуальные.

Аналогичные утилиты - [il-repack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack), [Mono.Merge](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2006/11/06/an-introduction-to-mono-merge/)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле вам нужна проверка на зависимости, а не костыльно-ориентированное решение на отдельных сборках с подпорками ilmerge. Архитектурно верно будет реализовать проверку с помощью анализаторов на базе нового компилятора Roslyn, который доступен в Visual Studio 2015 или выше.

Если вы реализуете нужный вам анализатор, то результаты анализа будут доступны вам в списке ошибок в студии ещё до компиляции, и нарушения будут подсвечены прямо в коде.

См. [C# and Visual Basic - Use Roslyn to Write a Live Code Analyzer for Your API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx) и другие статьи по теме.