# Как скомпилировать все проекты солюшена в один .EXE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть солюшен (Solution). В нем 4 проекта. Один главный, три второстепенных. Главный проект использует типы из второстепенных и наоборот. Короче все они переплетены. Как все это скомпилировать в один .EXE файл для последующего распространения?

**UPD**
Т.к. похоже,что не все поняли о чем речь, то постараюсь дополнить свой вопрос.

Вот небольшой пример:
В solution Explorer видно, что в Solution добавлено два проект. Проект App2 зависит от проекта App1. App1 добавлен в References.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же прописаны соответствующие зависимости.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если просто откомпилировать этот Solution, то на выходе получим два файла - App2.exe и App1.dll. Таким образом, чтобы приложение заработало, скажем на другом компьютере, нужно переписать туда два этих файла. Иначе произойдет ошибка времени выполнения. Что-то вроде ***Could not load file or assembly. The system cannot find the file specified***. Так вот хотелось бы откомпилировать приложение таким образом, чтобы в итоге получился только один файл - App2.exe. И чтобы распространять это приложение можно было одним файлом. А файл App1.dll была как бы встроена в него.

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? Почему нельзя деплоить один .exe и три .dll?

Comment: Можно, но хотелось бы одним файлом, если это возможно.

Comment: Сразу скомпилировать в один общий exe нельзя. Но можно слить несколько dll/exe в один уже после сборки. Посмотрите ответы по ссылке.

Comment: Или, как вариант, можно влить ваши dll [как ресурсы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457518/177221) - но я бы вам посоветовал вариант с ilmerge - это нормальный официальный (tm) способ, а не самописный костыль.

Comment: Да, ILMerge помог. Добавил в Post-build events вот эту строку 

***"$(SolutionDir)ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /out:"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).all.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).exe" "$(TargetDir)*.dll" /target:exe /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 /wildcards***

Работает замечательно!

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Проверка на отсутствие циклических ссылок при сборке из нескольких проектов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/51432)

Comment: Аналогично для .net 5: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1282216/213987

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Возможные решения:

## Слияние сборок в одну после компиляции

Несколько сборок можно склеить в одну уже после компиляции, используя утилиту [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx).

Она есть на [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge):

```
Install-Package ilmerge
```

Формат вызова:

```
ilmerge
  /lib:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"
  /lib:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"
  /targetplatform:v4
  /out:out.dll mydll1.dll mydll2.dll
```

перед использованием пути стоит подправить на актуальные.

Аналогичные утилиты - [il-repack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack), [Mono.Merge](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2006/11/06/an-introduction-to-mono-merge/)

## Включение DLL в EXE в виде Embedded Resource с подменой стандартного механизма загрузки:

1. Добавить `bin\someassembly.dll` в проект exe через Add Existing Item / стрелка на Add / Add as Link, выставить Build Type = Embedded Resource
2. Добавить проект `someassembly` в References. Выставить у референса Copy Local = false - чтобы избежать копирования в bin.
3. Обработать `CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve`:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
   {
       static class Program
       {
           [STAThread]
           static void Main()
           {
               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

               Application.EnableVisualStyles();
               Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
               Application.Run(new Form1());
           }

           private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
           {
               var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;
               if (assemblyName == "someassembly")
               {
                   using (var stream = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
                       "WindowsFormsApplication7." + assemblyName + ".dll"))
                   {
                       byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                       stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                       return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   return null;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Это минимальный рабочий пример. Если не работает - запускайте под отладчиком. Скорее всего вы не угадали с именем ресурса, и `GetManifestResourceStream` возвращает `null`. Убедитесь, что тип у айтема выставлен именно в Embedded Resource (а не просто в Resource). Просмотреть имена всех доступных ресурсов можно прямо в отладчике, вызовом

```
typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
```

Проект целиком на гитхабе, на примере SevenZipSharp: https://github.com/PashaPash/SevenZipSharp-Embedded

## Включение сборок в виде ресурсов, автоматический вариант

Устанавливаете пакет [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) через nuget и получаете один exe на выходе.

```
> PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

## Альтернативы:

- [Решение от Vlad - компиляция в netmodule с последющим слиянием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454191/177221)
- [Сборка через добавление всех исходников в еще один большой проект - от @Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468997/177221)

Answer (score 4):

Для .NET 5.0* есть более простое, поддерживаемое Microsoft решение: [single file deployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file).

Вам нужно настроить *публикацию*. Зайдите в Build → Publish, создайте профиль публикации. Обязательно выберите конкретный target runtime (например, Windows 64 bit), не оставляйте portable.

[image: как-то так]

Вы сможете также выбрать deployment mode = self-contained, при этом в файл добавится и весь используемый .NET, устанавливать на пользовательском компьютере .NET Runtime не придётся (но размер файла существенно вырастет). Также можно запросить ReadyToRun-компиляцию (то есть, AOT).

Всё!

---

*На самом деле, должно работать и с .NET Core 3.0, но я не проверял.

Answer (score 1):

Поправлю сам себя, решить проблему Вам поможет маленькая утилита от Microsoft - ILMerge. Добавлю, что есть хорошая [статья на данную тему](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126089/)

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё и костыльный способ: создать новый проект и в него добавить как существующие все файлы с кодом, после чего скомпилировать.

Comment: @cyadvert, почему не является? Именно ответом и является.

Comment: Можно добавить файлы как link - и, кстати, не такой уж костыльный способ.

Comment: @PashaPash, не знаю, что ты имеешь в виду под link. Студия и так позволит включить одни и те же файлы в несколько проектов.

Comment: @LEQADA, виноват, ребят, честно - палец дернулся... Это ж Qwertiy сообщение - даже не проверяю хотел пропустить... промахнулся

Comment: @Qwertiy да, и кнопка которая это делает, подписана как add as link :)

Comment: @PashaPash, когда я это однажды делал, использовал "Add Existing Item" - неужели переименовали?

Comment: @cyadvert, а почему мои сообщения надо сразу пропускать? о_О

Comment: :) потому что вопрос по c#, а я в нем совсем не шарю. А у тебя с репутацией все в порядке: муть не напишешь... Следовательно я хотел пропустить, не читая... :) Извини, задумался о другом комментарии, вот и нажал бред....

Comment: @Qwertiy add exiting item по дефолту копирует файл в текущий проект. Но в самом диалоге есть стрелка на кнопке, по которой выпадает дропдаун со второй опцией - add as link. Которая не копирует, а просто линкует существующий файл