# Можно ли добавить библиотеку в exe?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013

Я написал небольшой проект в VS 2013, используя стороннюю библиотеку (DLL). Теперь рядом с экзешником приходится постоянно держать эту библиотеку. Нельзя ли встроить эту библиотеку в проект или хотя бы необходимую часть кода, что бы не приходилось повсюду таскать эту dllку?

Comment: @Vitokhv этот вопрос - полный дубликат вопроса по ссылке. Это точно такой же вопрос с точно такими же решениями (ресурсы + AssemblyResolve или ilmerge). Если это не так - покажите, что именно в вопросе отличается. По поводу стиля общения - перечитайте, пожалуйста, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice/.

Comment: @Vitokhv ваш вопрос, кстати, тоже дубликат. как вам указали в комментариях, Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll вшивается в exe точно так же - вшиванием в ресурсы или прогоном ilmerge. Нет никакой разницы, подключена dll как соседний проект или подключена через nuget.

Comment: Объяснение простое, если бы Вы указали мой дубликат на эту тему, у меня бы отпали все вопросы. Но Вы почему то решили, что та тема главнее тех, которые действительно важны. Мне больше подходит ответ в этой теме, чем в другой.

Comment: @Vitokhv это не "я решил" - это правила сайта - на одну конкретную проблему - *один* вопрос с ответами от нескольких участников. Тот ответ, который вам подошел больше - практически полная копия решения №2 из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471236/177221 - тот же механизм, тот же обработчик, код отличается незначительными деталями. Да, детали важны - и механизим дубликатов как раз и существует для того, чтобы собрать в одном вопросе ответы от разных авторов. А не заставлять участников искать "подходящий ответ" [по десятку одинаковых тем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/468942?lq=1)

Comment: @Vitokhv та тема выбрана как целевая для дубликата потому что она создана на пол года раньше, чем эта. Т.е. когда топикастер пришел сюда с вопросом - там уже был готовый ответ. Было бы наоборот - закрыли бы наоборот.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, можно. Зависимую библиотеку можно встроить в ресурсы и подгружать оттуда вручную.
Предполагается, что ваша библиотека уже находится в References проекта, проект собирается, программа успешно запускается.

Для начала добавьте в проект библиотеку как ресурс:

- Меню Project -> Add Existing Item... - выбираете вашу сборку (dll, в диалоге открытия выберите тип файлов Executable Files). Библиотека появится в списке файлов проекта.
- Вызовите контекстное меню на добавленном файле, выберите Properties. Затем установите в открывшемся окне Build Actions -> Embedded Resource.

Добавьте в ваш проект следующий класс:

```
public static class Resolver
{
    private static volatile bool _loaded;

    public static void RegisterDependencyResolver()
    {
        if (!_loaded) {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnResolve;
            _loaded = true;
        }
    }

    private static Assembly OnResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Assembly execAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resourceName = String.Format("{0}.{1}.dll",
            execAssembly.GetName().Name,
            new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name);

        using (var stream = execAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) {
            int read = 0, toRead = (int)stream.Length;
            byte[] data = new byte[toRead];

            do {
                int n = stream.Read(data, read, data.Length - read);
                toRead -= n;
                read += n;
            } while (toRead > 0);

            return Assembly.Load(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Этот класс загрузит зависимую сборку из ресурса, как только основная программа
обратится к ней, используя обработчик события [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx).

В классе, где находится точка входа программы, добавьте статический конструктор и вызовите метод `RegisterDependencyResolver`. 
Для примера, пусть у вас имеется консольное приложение:

```
class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        Resolver.RegisterDependencyResolver();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Заботиться о выгрузке сборки не надо, т.к. это все равно невозможно (можно выгрузить только домен целиком).

Пример подсмотрен в книге Дж. Рихтера "CLR via C#".

Comment: Шикарно! Спасибо огромное, все работает!

Comment: _"stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);"_ - кто-то гарантирует, что всё содержимое будет отдано сразу?

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил.

Comment: @kmv спасибо за этот развернутый ответ, все по полочкам и понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант - использовать [ILMerge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge). Но писать скрипт для "склеивания" придется вручную, интеграции со студией из коробки нет.

Также такой вариант будет работать не для любой библиотеки; если библиотека активно использует рефлексию - возможно потребуется написать свой обработчик `AssemblyResolve`:

```
var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
  if (args.Name == "имя внедренной сборки") return assembly;
  return null;
};
```

Главное достоинство варианта с ILMerge при работе с несколькими проектами - не требуется помещать один и тот же код загрузчика в каждый проект; поскольку обработчик `AssemblyResolve` нужен только для рефлексии - можно поместить его в общую библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте утилиту ILMerge, а точнее ILMergeGUI
Отличная утилита, упаковывает все DLL в EXE