# Как поместить библиотеки в исполняемый файл

Tags: c#

Пишу програмку на шарпе и столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть сторонняя библиотека, которую я кидаю в папку с проектом, подключаю пространство имён и всё работает как надо. НО! для того, чтобы эту программу перенести на другой ПК нужно копировать всю папку вместе с библиотеками. Вопрос: как можно все эти файлы уместить в конечный исполняемый файл, чтобы был 1 exе и не было надобности копировать всю папку?

Comment: А что, это проблема? Ну используйте ILMerge.

Comment: А почему не сработало? В чём была проблема?

Comment: используйте GUI ILMerge там все просто - https://ilmergegui.codeplex.com/

Comment: Есть программа "ILMerge", сам не пробовал, не было необходимости. На хабре отлично об этом рассказано https://habrahabr.ru/post/126089/

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Может, у вас была библиотека на C++/CLI или что-то ещё с неуправляемым кодом? Такое по идее должно быть сложнее смёржить.

Answer (score 3):

Можно создать setup.exe с помощью, например, Inoo Setup. Указываете ей папку, где у вас лежит всё (включая ваш exe), и она создает вам setup.exe, при запуске которого вылезет стандартный установщик, он и создаст на чужом компьютере вашу папку со всем необходимым.
Правда, если в вашей папке есть вложенные папки, то там есть одна тонкость

Answer (score 3):

Как это делаю я:

1. Добавляю сборку как обычный файл явно в проект.
2. Указываю сборке (пкм по ней, свойства) Build Action - Embedded Resource, Do not copy.
3. На запуске приложения подписываюсь на событие резолва сборок

   ```
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly.ResolveInternalAssembly;

   internal static Assembly ResolveInternalAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   {
     var resource = args.Name;
     var resourceNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
     if (!resourceNames.Any())
       return null;

     if (resource.Contains(','))
       resource = resource.Substring(0, resource.IndexOf(','));

     var assemblyFile = string.Format(".{0}.dll", resource);
     var resourceName = resourceNames.SingleOrDefault(s => s.EndsWith(assemblyFile));
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceName))
     {
       assemblyFile = assemblyFile.Remove(0, 1);
       resourceName = resourceNames.SingleOrDefault(s => s.EndsWith(assemblyFile));
     }

     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceName))
       return null;

     using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
     {
       var block = new byte[stream.Length];
       stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
       return Assembly.Load(block);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Не надо давать копипасту своего ответа на разные вопросы. Разные вопросы подразумевают разные ответы. Если ответ совсем одинаков - значит, вопросы надо объединять как дубликаты.

Comment: @PavelMayorov давать только ссылку - не является ответом. Вопрос - дублем в принципе не является, хотя не мне решать. Лучше бы я пометил вопрос дублем?

Comment: На самом деле, проблема в том вопросе, а не в этом. Тот вопрос - довольно плохого качества, не стоило на него отвечать вовсе...

Comment: @Monk выбирайте какой из ответов вам милее - тот или этот. И снесите один из них

Comment: @PavelMayorov перелинковал дубликат на  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/

Answer (score 2):

Я использую [Costura.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/). Просто устанавливаешь через nuget и все dll внедряются в exe