# Как сохранить телеграмм бот в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Всем доброго времени суток! Написал первый простенький телеграм бот на С#, суть в том что он проверяет записи в Гугл таблице и если на завтра есть мероприятие, то пишет мне от этом. Как его грамотно сохранить , чтобы в дальнейшем была возможность развернуть на каком-нибудь сервере?

Comment: Что значит *грамотно сохранить*?

Comment: @Anatol просто вытаскивать exe из файлов проекта не работает

Comment: Вероятно, ваш exe использует другие библиотеки/конфиги. Чтобы "грамотно сохранить", смотрите в Студии меню Build > Publish.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468942/183842

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Интуитивно предполагаю, что ты хочешь сборку собрать в один файл. Если да, то - ILMerge в помощь. Ссылка на туториал по использованию - https://habrahabr.ru/post/126089/

Comment: Интуиция не основание для ответа