# Создание dll с внешними библиотеками

Tags: c#

Есть 10 внешних библиотек, которые я подключаю к своему классу. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать, чтобы при компиляции у меня получился 1 общий dll. И не нужно было везде таскать с собой эти 10 внешних библиотек?

Необходимо скомпилировать всё не в exe файл, а создать dll файл из нескольких вложенных dll

Comment: Смотрите: [это1](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126089/), [это2](https://geektimes.ru/post/67836/) или [это3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one). Почитайте внимательно статьи и комменты. У каждого способа есть свои подводные камни.

Comment: @John хорошо, всё прочту, спасибо большое!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как скомпилировать все проекты солюшена в один .EXE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-exe)