# Встраивание библиотеки в приложени

Tags: c#, dll

Здравствуйте, есть библиотека для работы с `ru-captcha`, если библиотека находиться рядом с исполняемым файлом - проблем нет. Но если библиотеки рядом нет, то вылезает ошибка. Как встроить библиотеку в саму программу при компиляции? То есть, что бы не нужно было иметь библиотеку рядом с исполняемым файлом/в папке system32

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как скомпилировать все проекты солюшена в один .EXE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-exe)

Comment: Обратите внимание на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable) вопрос с английского SO