# Внедрить dll в exe

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить код ниже (c# winforms vs2010). Сейчас выдает ошибку "Не удалось загрузить файл Newtonsoft.Json.dll". 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом файл exe после компиляции по размеру включает этот dll. Newtonsoft.Json.dll добавлен в проект, копировать локально=false.

Файл dll загружен из https://json.codeplex.com/releases (взят из папки bin/net40). Выбрано: копировать в выходной каталог=не копировать, действие при построении=внедренный ресурс.
Использую:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("EmbedAssembly.Newtonsoft.Json.dll"))
            {
                byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы смотрели dll присутствует в папке с exe?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как скомпилировать все проекты солюшена в один .EXE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-exe)

Comment: Можно попробовать вариант собрать Newtonsoft.Json.dll из исходников, потом внедрять как ресурс. Помнится, получал эту ошибку на 32 битной Виндоуз. Для х64,  с готовыми собранными длл, такой проблемы как у Вас не возникает.

Comment: Добавила dll в ресурс. Ошибка все равно возникает.

Comment: Взять Enigma Virtual Box и больше не придумывать сложных схем объединения всех файлов в один. https://enigmaprotector.com/en/aboutvb.html

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnResolveAssembly;
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private static Assembly OnResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs e)
        {
            var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(e.Name);
            var dllName = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";

            var resources = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(s => s.EndsWith(dllName));
            if (resources.Any())
            {
                var resourceName = resources.First();

                using (var stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                {
                    if (stream == null) return null;
                    var block = new byte[stream.Length];

                    try
                    {
                        stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
                        return Assembly.Load(block);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```