# C# WPF AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget

Устанавливаю AvalonDock через NuGet и все нормально работает, но я бы хотел использовать [source code](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit) в проекте. Копирую классы и все остальное и VS 2017 видит xmlns но бросает ошибки на сами теги. Пишет что не видит DockingManager в namespace и подобное. Изменял на `"clr-namespace: ..."` все находит но не рендерит, проект запускается и ничего не видно.

Comment: Вы код к себе в проект скопировали или что?

Comment: @Андрей NOP да, папку AvalonDock

Comment: А в чем смысл данных деяний? Хотите объединить, то этот вопрос смело можно отмечать [дубликатом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/Как-скомпилировать-все-проекты-солюшена-в-один-exe/471236#471236). Если же хотите взять исходники, изменить их и подключить, то смотрите что не так в зависимостях, есть ли ссылки на тот или иной проект, последовательность запуска какая. Много факторов...

Comment: А если указать явный неймспейс для контрола, типа `xmlns:c="clr-namespace:My.Name.Space"`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP указал clr-namespace

Comment: @АндрейNOP теперь ошибок нет но AvalonDock не рендерит (код добавил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как подключать сторонние проекты в свой:

1. Скачиваем исходный код.
2. Распаковываем в директорию рядом с нашим проектом (либо в любом другом месте). В вашем случае там две папки, одна из которых заканчивается на "_35" - это версия .NET 3.5.
3. В основном проекте жмём правой кнопкой мыши по нашему решению - Добавить - Существующий проект.

[image: Add Project]

4. Выбираем файл `.csproj` нужного компонента (у вас это `ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution\Src\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.csproj`).
5. Пересоберите все решение, должно собраться без ошибок. Если они есть - ищем виновника, может проект на что то ссылается. В  итоге в консоле должны увидеть:

```
========== Перестроение всех проектов: успешно: 2, с ошибками: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

6. Если ошибок нет, то двигаемся дальше, а именно, добавление в основном проекте ссылки на сторонний. Жмём у нашего проекта ПКМ по "Ссылки" - "Добавить ссылку".
7. В появившемся окне сбоку выбираем "Проекты", там увидим сторонний проект. Выбираем его "галкой" и жмём ок.

[image: Add Ref]

8. Желательно ещё раз пересобрать решение. Далее мы можем работать с этим компонентом. Я возьму код из [документации](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/AvalonDock), уберу только из него все лишнее.
9. Я не знаю как лично у вас, но у меня при написание XAML кода сама студия предлагает добавить недостающие пути на ту или иную сборку, если у вас не так, то не забываем добавить вручную:

   ```
   xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
   ```

Ура, можно запускать!

[image: Result]