# Можно ли внедрить dll в exe?

Tags: c#, dll

В свой проект я добавил библиотеку DotNetZip. На моем компьютере скомпилированная программа работает, а когда я запускаю на другом компьютере, у меня возникает следующая ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Невозможно загрузить
>        файл или сборку "DotNetZip, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6
>       583c7c814667745" или один из зависимых от них компонентов. Не удается найти указанный файл.
>          в DownloadFilesDesktop.Program.DownloadFile()
>          в DownloadFilesDesktop.Program.Main(String[] args)

Как я понял, это из-за того что не хватает библиотеки DotNetZip. Как это можно исправить? Можно ли полностью внедрить dll в exe?

Comment: а просто библиотеку закинуть к exe почему нельзя?

Comment: Вы предлагаете везде тащить библиотеку?

Comment: Да, потому что это внешняя библиотека по отношению к вашему проекту. Почти все продукты, имеющие внешние зависимости, поставляются со всеми библиотеками, которые они используют в процессе работы, если нет точной уверенности в том, что эти библиотеки будут на компьютере каждого потенциального пользователя.

Comment: Нельзя как нибудь при выходе получить один exe, с внедренными библиотеками?

Comment: @guno7, вопрос: зачем? чтобы исполняемый файл был больше?

Comment: У меня исполняемый файл всего лишь 10 кб. Не страшно если добавится к нему 2-3 мб.

Comment: Возможно [это](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1781010.html) вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

1) от самой библиотеки в проекте не избавиться никак. чтобы не таскать ее на разные ПК используйте nuget

2) про создание одного exe, в котором все dll
https://habr.com/post/126089/

Comment: На второй пункт можно и на SO найти информации море, особенно [эта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471236/220553) тема довольно интересная...