# Как внедрить System.Data в exe?

Tags: c#

На компьютере у одного пользователя не установлен SqlClient. Соответственно у меня используются экземпляры класса System.Data.SqlClient. И у него программа не работает. Пыталась собирать класс с установленным признаком "Внедрить типы взаимодействия". Выдается ошибка: Внедрение типов взаимодействия из сборки "c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll" невозможно, поскольку у нее отсутствует атрибут "ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute" или атрибут "PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute".   c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll
Что можно сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как скомпилировать все проекты солюшена в один .EXE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-exe)

Answer (score 2):

Классы из System.Data.SqlClient являются частью .NET Framework. Если у кого то их нету, им нужно переустановить .NET Framework.

Параметр "Внедрить типы взаимодействия" можно применять только для сборок, являющихся обертками для взаимодействия с библиотекой COM-объектов. Для внедрения произвольных сборок смотрите в сторону [ILMerge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge).

Comment: Я так поняла, что у него все же установлен .Net Framework. Есть папка c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 и в ней System.Data.dll

Comment: @DHel Ну, может она повреждена. А какую конкретно ошибку пишет на его компьютере?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/4.7.0-preview.18571.3) пакет для этого и развертываете ваше приложение "закрыто". Производите копировани всех сборок, модулей и файлов-ресурсов при разворачивании на целевую машину.