# Как запустить программу вне среды Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017, catel

Я создал программу на WPF с помощью фреймворка Catel. И она отлично работает, но ровно до того момента, пока лежит в папке output\Debag. Если программу куда-либо перенести, то она просто не открывается (на 10-ке) или пишет "Неудалось отрыть средствами Виндовс"(на 8-ке). При этом проблема не в самой программе, ибо я создал пустой проект, и он ведет себя точно также. Подскажите чем вызвано такое поведение и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вы переносите только .exe файл?

Comment: @Hazatdum да только .exe

Comment: Вам нужно переносить файл со всеми dll библиотеками, лежащими в папке debug, попробуйте

Comment: @Hazatdum спасибо работает, но как тогда можно поделится с кем-то экзешником не пересылая кучу библиотек?

Comment: Можно создать инсталлятор программы, а можно посмотреть вот сюда: https://github.com/Fody/Costura

Comment: @Hazatdum спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471236/220553