# c# собрать проект в ехе файл

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, сборка

как получить самостоятельный ехе файл? который можно например отправить по почте без каких то дополнительных файлов типа библиотек

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как скомпилировать все проекты солюшена в один .EXE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-exe)

Comment: Уточните: может у вас .NET Core? В проектах этого типа нет exe-файлов вообще, только dll.