# Помогите скомпилировать программу на C# с помощью csc. Не получается подключить внешнюю ссылку. FileNotFound Exception

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
Мне нужно скомпилировать программу написанную на C# с помощью csc.exe.
Пишу так: `csc /out:C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\123.exe /t:exe C:\Users\Asus\source\repos\steal\steal\Program.cs /r:Ionic.Zip.dll`
Происходит всё без ошибок, но когда запускаю пишет:

```
Необработанное исключение: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.1.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=edbe51ad942a3f5c" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
   в steal.Program.Main()
```

Помогите, как правильно сделать? Мучаюсь уже час. dll лежит в папке.

Comment: Когда запускаете - dll лежит в одной папке с exe?

Comment: Уточню: когда **запускаете** - dll лежит в одной папке с exe? Не когда **компилируете** (компиляция у вас проходит успешно), а когда **запускаете**. После компиляции нужно ту библиотеку скопировать в нужную папку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , да, пофиксилось, но теперь еще одна проблема - мне нужно что бы была одна exe, без dll, можно как то вшить этот dll?

Comment: Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях, создавайте для этого новую тему. \ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471236/184217