# Инсталлер для программы

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10

У меня есть форма написаная в visual studio на c#

После того как я ее скомпилировал у меня появилось несколько файлов некоторые из которых имеют зависимость от exe файла моей формы

Вопрос заключается в том ,что мне нужно все эти файлы собрать в один файл либо сделать инсталятор для програмы ,который будет все эти файлы устанавливать в одно место, НО я незнаю как это сделать ,а програм которые делают инсталятор под win 10 я не нашел

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942

Comment: у меня еще файлы бд которые нельзя слепить вместе по этому методу

Comment: Тогда мне не понятен ваш вопрос. Что мешает просто создать архив? Будет вам 1 файл. Хорошо, не нравиться это, используйте например `ClickOnce`. Не нравиться он, идете в гугл и пишете "создать установщик" и видим кучу программ для этого (`Inno Setup`, `Smart Install Maker` и др.). Не нравятся они, так напишите свою программу, благо C# очень гибкий язык! P.S. При чем тут Win10? На сколько я знаю, она любой .exe файл без труда открывает. Так что если у вас программа для создания установщика написана под winXP, то на Win10 она должна запуститься.

Comment: Спасибо, и да я гуглил и видел Smart Install Maker просто думал про совместимость