# Собрать в кучу все файлы программы

Tags: wpf

Вопрос такой, как собрать все файлы в один exe файл, есть какие-то нормальные способы, кроме Winrar'a?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как скомпилировать все проекты солюшена в один .EXE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-exe)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я видел что есть целое приложение посвященное этому всему, не могли бы вы поделиться рабочей ссылкой на ILMerge-Gui, ищу второй день, не получается найти рабочий вариант

Comment: `Costura.Fody` установите да и все. а ILMerge - это консольная программа, да, энтузиасты сделали ей оболочку но все же, лучше использовать консоль.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не найдется ли  у вас актуального примера того, как использовать `Costura.Fody`?

Comment: Вы сами то пробовали? Ей богу, просто установить пакет через NUGet , прописать одну строку в сгенерированном .xml файле (вроде в последних версиях делает сам) и все, попробуйте, это просто!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Так я добавил его в проект, и дальше что делать? Ничего не понятно, и прочитать об этом негде. Не добавляет он сгенерированный файл xml в проект.

Comment: А он у вас и не добавит XML в проект, ибо он там не нужен, как и .pdb, как по сути и .config (если в него не прописаны настройки). Его цель, это объединить все сборки в одну, сборками являются .dll и .exe.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Подскажите пожалуйста, а если я допустим настройки программы сохраняю в `settings.json` оно тоже объеденит всё в один `exe`  файл?

Comment: Я уже вроде дал выше ответ, соберет все .dll и .exe в один. Файлы настроек вы хоть раз видели внутри программы? Я - нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Хорошо, есть ещё какие-то нормальные методы сборки приложения в 1 exe?

Comment: Опять же, ссылка выше, там описаны все методы. Самый нормальный я вам дал, лучше - не найдете.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на этот вопрос уже есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-exe).

Если ответы из того вопроса Вам не подходят, то в качестве альтернативы, можно использовать следующие решения:

- Создать единый установщик для всех компонентов программы.
- Хранить конфиги вашей программы в отдельной постоянной папке.
  (Например: "C:\Users\username_here\Documents\Test_Project\Test_Project.config")

P.S. Получить директорию документов для текущего пользователя, можно с помощью команды `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` в C#.