# Как скомпилировать файлы и папки в один .exe

Tags: c#

Я экспортировал все внутриновсти спомощью dotPeek, получил папки и файлы. Мне нужно было немного подкоректировать код(добавить пару ссылок), я сделал всё что нужно, но тут следующая проблема, я декомпилировал и экспортировать смог а вот скомпилировать ПАПКИ и ФАЙЛИ по типу .cs , .csproj , .sln , и другие... Вот как скомпилировать папки и файлы обратно в один .exe?(Желательно без Visual studio и Visual studio code)

Comment: P.S. Переписывать ой как не хочется

Comment: компилятор скачай любой: например mono

Comment: с помощью компилятора, но в процессе декомпиляции вы можете получить не валидный код, поэтому его нужно будет поправить руками, если вам нужно было поменять несколько ссылок, то тулзы, которые позволяют поменять IL код, тогда не нужно будет компилировать с нуля

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как скомпилировать все проекты солюшена в один .EXE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468942/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-exe)