# C# WPF не работает команда dotnet publish

Tags: c#, wpf

я хочу собрать свое WPF приложение со всеми его зависимостями в архив с .exe файлом, чтобы я мог перекидывать готовый проект на другие компьютеры. Из глубин интернета я выудил, что мне может помочь вот эта команда

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r win-x64
```

Но при попытке запустить ее с моим wpf проектом, я получаю вот такую гору ишибок

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine версии 16.9.0+57a23d249 для .NET
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

  Определение проектов для восстановления...
  Работы нет. Ни в одном из указанных проектов нет пакетов, которые можно было бы восстановить.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3136,5): error MSB4216: не удалось выполнить задачу "GenerateResource", поскольку MSBuild не удалось создать сервер задач со средой выполнения "CLR4" и архитектурой "x86" или подключиться к нему.  Убедитесь, что (1) запрошенные среда выполнения и архитектура существуют на компьютере и (2) необходимый исполняемый файл "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\MSBuild.exe" существует и может быть запущен. [D:\Code\Decoder_Study\Decoder_Study\Decoder_Study.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3158,7): error MSB4028: не удалось получить выходные спецификации задачи "GenerateResource" из параметра "FilesWritten". Object does not match target type. [D:\Code\Decoder_Study\Decoder_Study\Decoder_Study.csproj]
```

И я понятия не имею в чем проблема, а интернет только запутывает. Проект не очень сложный, но использует стороннюю тему Material Desing. В проекте многое разбито на разные файлы, лежащие в разных директориях(Например, классы и flowdocument'ы)

В файле **App.config** нашел вот такую строчку. Возможно это поможет.

`<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />`

Comment: `Framework` != `.net Core`! Они разные, у них разные подходы. Хотите фреймворк объединить - [дерзайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468942/220553).

Comment: это должно вам помочь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/building-a-wpf-application-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8