Как сделать так, что бы у меня подгружался папка/файл в .exe в C#
Такая проблема, мне нужно сделать - единый .exe файл, как мне поместить папку и .dll что бы оно работало и не требовалось 2 этих файла рядом.

WindowsInput.dll 
Assets


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468942/184217 ЗЫ: эта ссылка наверняка показывается вам справа в блоке "Похожие". Просто смотрите вокруг, что вам предлагает сайт

Что именно находится в папке Assets, файлы какого типа? В общем случае, можно помещать файлы любых типов в "Ресурсы" (Resources). Поищите информацию сами. Не найдёте решения - приходите с конкретным вопросом, что не получается.

1 и 2 это два разных вопроса, на которые есть 2 разных ответа.

Никак. Библиотеки на то и библиотеки, что они являются как бы подключаемыми модулями. Если хотите использовать библиотеку, вам нужно включить её в свой проект. С папками аналогично.
По факту, вам .exe (executable) файл является набором команд для выполнения других частей программы или кода. Этот код может располагаться в сторонних библиотеках (Те, который будут добавлены в папку вашего проекта с расширением .dll) либо структурирован по папкам/подпапкам (Которые так же будут включены в финальную сборку проекта)

Никак? Ну это как минимум неправда.
